# Export SQL Results to an excel file - Teradata Studio Express

Tags: teradata

Teradata Studio Express, Version 16.2

I queried from an oracle database using TSE's SQL file editor (Since it is a non-TeraData database or else I would be using TSE's Teradata SQL editor). When querying from SQL File Editor, TSE provides the result within the **SQL Results** panel.

> What I want to do is to export the result to an excel file but it does
>   not provide an option to do so. How do I approach this?

Below is a screenshot comparing result set panels. The left panel (querying from Teradata SQL Editor) has an option to export to excel but the right panel (Querying SQL File Editor) does not.

[image]

Comment: I think if you select the entire resultset and 'copy' it, you can then paste it into the Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.. Don't know why they don't provide a export option icon yet but here is solution:

Right click on the result table.

It will provides options. Select **Export**, then **Current Result...**

Then this window will appear (save it as a csv file and you should be able to open with Excel):

[image]